# C++ AMP Division Quirk When Stressing GPU

Tags: c++-amp

Wrote a program that uses C++ AMP to run on my laptop's GPU (Intel HD Graphics 520).  The GPU kernel is long so I will give a high level description (but let me know if more is needed).

Note that I fall into the "know enough to be dangerous" category of programmer.

```
parallel_for_each(accelerator_view, number_of_runs.extent, [data](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
{
double total = data.starting_total[idx];
//these "working variables" are used for a variety of things in the code
double working_variable = 0.0; 
double working_variable2 = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{

...do lots of stuff. "total" is changed by various factors...

//total is still a positive number that is greater than zero
//working_variable now has a positive non-zero value, and I want to find what % 
//of the remaining total that value is
working_variable2 = 1.0 / total;
working_variable2 = working_variable * working_variable2;

//Note that if I write it like this the same issue will happen:
working_variable2 = working_variable / total;

...keep going and doing more things, write some values to data..

if (total == 0)
break;
}

}
```

When I run this without doing much else on my computer this runs just fine and I get the results I expect.

Where it gets really tricky is when I am stressing the system (or I think I am stressing the system).  I test stress the system by
1) Kicking off my program
2) Opening up Chrome
3) Going to Youtube and starting a video

When I do that I get unexpected results (either when I am opening a program or running a video).  I traced it back to the "1.0 / total" calculation returning infinity (inf), even though "total" is greater than zero.  Here is an example of what I output to the console when this issue happens:

```
total = 51805.6
1.0 / total = inf
precise_math::pow(total, -1) = 1.93029e-05
```

I am running the kernel about 1.6 million times and I'll see between 0 and 15 of those 1.6 million hit this issue.  The number of issues varies and which threads hit the issue varies.

So I feel confident that "total" is not zero and this is not a divide by zero situation.  What am I missing? What could be causing this issue? Any way to prevent this?  I am thinking of replacing all division in the kernel with the pow(num, -1)

P.S. Yes I am aware that the part of the answer is "don't watch videos while running".  It is the opening of programs during execution that I am most concerned about.

Thank you!